# How to add a date and time to a PostgreSQL database with EF?

Tags: c#, database, postgresql

I have a data model, with the help of EF migration I created a data table based on this model.

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Theme { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Place { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

After that, I remembered that I forgot to add the date and time field. I added this field and created a new migration, after which I applied the update database command.

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Theme { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

When executing my request to update the date and time via the Web Api, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Unspecified to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only UTC is supported. Note that it's not possible to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior.

When executing my request to update the date and time via the Web Api, I get the following error. Before adding the date and time field, everything worked fine, with MSSQL everything also works fine and the date is added well.

Comment: So you made the DateTime stored in EventTime a UTC one and...

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot write DateTime with Kind=Unspecified to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp with time zone', only UTC is supported

That means you need to [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=net-6.0) your `EventTime` to UTC